# cx_Oracle and output variables

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, cx-oracle

I'm trying to do this again an Oracle 10 database:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
lOutput = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
cursor.execute("""
            BEGIN
                %(out)s := 'N';
            END;""",
            {'out' : lOutput})
print lOutput.value
```

but I'm getting

```
DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Is it possible to define PL/SQL blocks in cx_Oracle this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do anonymous PL/SQL blocks.  Your bind variable for the output parameter is not in the correct format.  It should be `:out` instead of `%(out)s`

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
lOutput = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
cursor.execute("""
            BEGIN
                :out := 'N';
            END;""",
            {'out' : lOutput})
print lOutput
```

Which produces the output:

```
<cx_Oracle.STRING with value 'N'>
```

Comment: Many thanks...I thought we'd tried that particular combination at some point, but we must have missed it!

Comment: How can I change it if I use cursor.callproc("SOME_PROC',[lOutput])